# input value update with Jquery not working

Tags: jquery, input, drupal-7

I have a Drupal 7 site that I am trying to use Jquery to modify an exposed filter search form using Jquery.  It works for some input fields, but not the one I want.  Using the code below, **test-input-one** and **test-input-two** work fine, but the Drupal generated input field **edit-field-s-city-value** does not.  The Jquery code builds a drop down list then is supposed to update the other input boxes when the user selects something.

I am using drupal_add_js('misc/jscodefile.js'); in my ..views.tpl.php file to include my Jquery code.

The *material* Jquery code (I added the // comments)

```
$(document).ready(function($) {     
                ...           
                select: function( event, ui ) {
                log( ui.item ?
                    "Selected: " + ui.item.label :
                    "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
                $("#test-input-one").val(ui.item.mcity);  // this works!
                $("#test-input-two").val(ui.item.mstate); // this works!            
                $("#edit-field-s-city-value").val(ui.item.mcity);  // this does not work!!
                 ...
                });
```

The HTML generated by drupal with PHP is:

```
              <div id="edit-field-s-city-value-wrapper" class="views-exposed-widget views-widget-filter-field_s_city_value">
                  <label for="edit-field-s-city-value">
            City          </label>
                        <div class="views-widget">
          <div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-field-s-city-value">
 <input type="text" id="**edit-field-s-city-value**" name="field_s_city_value" value="" size="20" maxlength="30" class="form-text" />
</div>
        </div>
              </div>
          <div id="edit-field-s-zip-value-wrapper" class="views-exposed-widget views-widget-filter-field_s_zip_value">
                  <label for="edit-field-s-zip-value">
            Zip (field_s_zip)          </label>
                        <div class="views-widget">
          <div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-field-s-zip-value">
 <input type="text" id="edit-field-s-zip-value" name="field_s_zip_value" value="" size="10" maxlength="10" class="form-text" />
</div>
        </div>
              </div>
                    <div class="views-exposed-widget views-submit-button">
      <input type="submit" id="edit-submit-test-view" name="" value="Apply" class="form-submit" />    </div>
      </div>

  <input type="text" id="test-input-one" name="one_value" value="" size="18" maxlength="40" class="form-text">
  <input type="text" id="test-input-two" name="two_value" value="" size="6" maxlength="10" class="form-text">
```

I am thinking there is something funny with the nested divs, css tags or something, but I am at a loss.  Thanks.

Comment: Did you add the `**...**` to your id above, or is that really how it is in your html.

Comment: Is `ui.item.mcity` defined, and does it contain a value?

Comment: The asterisks are a formatting thing and not part of the code.  The three dots represent a bunch of code that I did not include since it is not relevant.

Comment: Yes, the ui.item.mcity have a value which successfully updates the first two input fields, but not the third.

Comment: I mean this `id="**edit-field-s-city-value**"`, the ... was in place of `edit-field-s-city-value`

Comment: Oh, that was a formatting thing as well.  I thought I removed it to avoid this exact confusion.  The tag is <input type="text" id="edit-field-s-city-value" name="field_s_city_value" value="" size="20" maxlength="30" class="form-text required" />

Comment: With those changes in mind, I don't see anything wrong. What do you get with `alert($("[id=edit-field-s-city-value]").length)`?

Comment: I get a dialogue box that pops up with a '2' in it (without the quotes).  I guess this means that the element is visible to the Jquery, yea?

Comment: That means you have duplicate Id's. Fix your duplicate ID problem and your problem will be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I could imagine this to go wrong is when the id "edit-field-s-city-value" is not unique.

Comment: YOU ARE CORRECT!  OMG, I didn't realize it, but there is another view with the same id on the page (and it is updating properly!)  Thank you for the brilliant observation.  This was under my nose the entire time.  Solved.